# Why am I unable to ping my host machine from vm machine even though the network is bridge?

Tags: vmware-workstation

I have been facing an issue with VMware which is unable to ping host machine from Guest Machin, but I'm able to ping guest machine from host machine.

Note: Here one more interesting matter is I could able to ping my host machine from guest machine with NAT network, but I couldn't ping my guest machine from host machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear at all.

In any case, you might wish yo specify what OS you are using in both nodes.

Firewall issues? You could try to disable Windows firewall for instance and locate where is the issue.

Could you give some basic data of the IP address of both nodes when the set up is in bridge mode?

Comment: Thank you..
  it resolved, when i stoped my firewall

Comment: Glad it helped. However, to disable firewall shouldn't be acceptable. So far try to add a specific rule for allowing ping communication. Dig deeper here: [allow ping icmp recho request](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/allow-pings-icmp-echo-request-through-your-windows-vista-firewall/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of disabling the firewall. Enable Rule "File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In)" from Inbound Rules on both Host and the VMWare Workstation. In some host machines or VMWare Workstation you may find multiple Rules with the same name "File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In)", make sure you enable all.